# Xpath - How to reach an attribute in a different branch with an id

Tags: xml, xpath

If I have an ID, IDRef pair, both of which in separate "branches", and want to reach an attribute of the parent element of an ID through the ID on the other branch, how should I go on about it?

For instance with this code:

```
<root>
   <element1>
      <element2 id="I01"/>
   </element1>
   <element3>
      <element4 idref="I01" attribute="example"
   </element3>
</root>
```

How would I reach the example attribute through element 2?

Comment: `//*[@idref = //element2/@id]/@attribute`

Comment: Share your XPath

Comment: It works, not quite the way I wanted it to but it works. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Although i don't like using these kind of xpaths but it could work for you

```
//*[@id="I01"]/..//element4[@attribute="example"]
```